# Child not appending in a node XML C#

Tags: c#, xml

I have been studying XML here in SO. I tried using `XDocument` to add a node inside.

My XML looks like this

```
<root>
  <parent>

  </parent>
</root>
```

And expected XML should be like

```
<root>
  <parent>
    <course>ABC</course>
    <credit>555</credit>
  </parent>
</root>
```

I wrote this code to achieve

```
 XDocument xml = XDocument.Load("root.xml");
 XElement root = xml.Root.Element("root");
 root.Element("parent").Add(new XElement("course", "ABC"));
```

But at 3rd line it gives

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Can any one help with explanation please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`XDocument.Root` is the root element in your document, in your case "root".

Therefore

```
xml.Root.Element("root");
```

is looking for a child element "root" of your root element, i.e:

```
<root>
    <root>
    ...
```

This doesn't exist, hence your null reference.

Try this:

```
xml.Root.Element("parent").Add(new XElement("course", "ABC"));
```

Comment: This isn't adding either.

Comment: Works now! My mistake. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This works :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument xml = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            XElement parent = xml.Descendants("parent").FirstOrDefault();

            parent.Add(new object[] {
                new XElement("course", "ABC"),
                new XElement("credit",555)
            });
        }
    }
}
```